# Jfreechart XYAreaChart multiple colors

Tags: jfreechart

Okay so useing Jfreechart I have these this dataset with two time series. I want to be able to chose which color is being used with each timeseries. I would like the first time series to be blue, and the next time series to be green. Right now though the graph seems to default to blue and purple and I cannot figure out why. Here is the code:

```
    public JFreeChart doProcess(final XYDataset dataset, String theDB) {
    //PlotOrientation orientation;
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(theDB
            + " AVERAGE ACTIVE SESSION GRAPH", "DATE (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI)", "ACTIVE SESSIONS", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true, true, false);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));// light gray
    final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    //plot.setOutlinePaint(Color.black);
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);   
    plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);   
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.65f);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    DateAxis d = new DateAxis();
    d.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
    d.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);
    d.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"));
    plot.setDomainAxis(d); 
    final ValueAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setTickMarkPaint(Color.black);
    domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);
    domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0);
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.GREEN);
    final ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setTickMarkPaint(Color.black);
    return chart;
}
```

All I want to do is color the top line blue and the bottom line green. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.  You should look at what you do to the chart instance **after** it is returned from the `doProcess()` method.  In particular, look out for any calls to `applyCurrentTheme()`.